# Jave Swing JButton must be clicked twice before form updates

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

This is such a bizarre problem (for me) that I'm not even sure how to ask it. I have a custom control NewOtherPaidOutsEntry that contains two text fields, a Save button and a Cancel button. The main window contains a form, and within that form is a list of optional OtherPaidOuts. The NewOtherPaidOutsEntry is added at the bottom of this list so the user can add entries to the list. 
I created an interface NewOtherPaidOutsListener with a single method newOtherPaidOutsActionEmitted, and a method in NewOtherPaidOutsEntry called setNewOtherPaidOutsListener. The parent form sets up this new entry like this (EditAction is just an enum, and note that I left out real exception handling for clarity):

```
private void setupNewEntry() {
    this.newEntry = new NewOtherPaidOutsEntry(this.shiftId);
    this.newEntry.setNewOtherPaidOutsListener((EditAction action) -> {
        try {
            handleNewOtherPaidOuts(action);
        } catch (Exception e) { 
           handleException(e);
        }
    });
}
```

And handleNewOtherPaidOuts is this:

```
private void handleNewOtherPaidOuts(EditAction action) {
    switch (action) {
        case SAVE:
            System.out.println("Save NewOtherPaidOuts");
            OtherPaidOutsController.addShiftOtherPaidOut(newEntry);
            newEntry.reset();
            layoutPanel();
            shiftLeftPane.update();
            break;
        case CANCEL:
            System.out.println("Cancel NewOtherPaidOuts");
            break;
    }
}
```

I put in the println statement and see it's being executed as soon as the button is clicked. If I step through in debug everything behaves normally. But if I just run the application the list of OtherPaidOuts isn't updated until I click the new entry's Save button a second time. The first time it's clicked the button stays depressed.

addShiftOtherPaidOut(newEntry) executes the database insert. newEntry.reset() just sets the two text fields to empty text. The list of OtherPaidOuts is in a JPanel OtherPaidOutsPane, with this as the layoutPanel() method:

```
protected void layoutPanel() {
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    add(createTitlePanel());
    add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
    getOtherPaidOutsEntries();        
    add(newEntry);
    add(Box.createVerticalGlue());       
}
```

The method getOtherPaidOutsEntries just gets a List of existing entries for this record and adds them to OtherPaidOutsPane. Then the OtherPaidOutsPane is embedded in another JPanel ShiftLeftPane.

I guess I could just use a dialog box for a new entry, but ... I thought I'd do my best with this route first.

My apologies if I haven't provided enough sample code, but this phase of the project is so entrenched it's difficult to give a runnable example. Please let me know what else I need to provide, I'll be happy to. And please understand that I'm flying by the seat of my pants, so be kind with any explanations ;-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you dynamically add components to a visible GUI the basic code is:

```
panel.add(....);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

By default the size of a Swing component is (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint(). You need the revalidate() to invoke the layout manager to the components are given a size and location based on the rules of the layout manager.

> I guess I could just use a dialog box for a new entry,

Didn't read your whole question in detail because it was too hard to get the context of what you are doing.

But if you have multiple entries of something then maybe you should be using a JTable to display the data. Then you could use a JDialog to prompt for the data and then add the data to the JTable. This is much easier to manager than trying to add/remove panels.

Comment: Sure enough, that fixed it. Thanks!! Like I said, I'm flying by the seat of my pants, sometimes learning what seems like a line at a time. I'll certainly look at your suggestion of using a JTable, because it sure feels like I'm reinventing the wheel here. Thanks again.